# C# How to implement a main object with additional objects?

Tags: c#

I have a main object which has some properties and methods. This object can have multiple parts. These parts are required. The amount of these parts is variable.

Each part has different properties and is referenced to the main object.

To accomplish this in my GUI I have a tabcontrol. The first tab is the main object. The other tabs describes the main object further. These 'other' tabs are the parts I mentioned above.

I am trying to design an architecture, but I can't figure I hope yoy can help me.

As suggested from the answers, the part-tabs inherit from an interface. But how does the main know about it's parts? The parts can't be hardcoded because it is variable. To hardcode the parts is a violation of the OCP principle.

Also, when loading the main object, again, how does it knows about it parts? I have to 'register' them somewhere, but where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create interface for your parts, that can have reference to main object. And main object will contain collection of parts as `Collection<IPart>`

```
class MainObject
{
    Collection<IPart> Parts {get;set;}
}

interface IPart
{
    MainObject MainObject {get;set;}
}

class SomePartImpl : IPart
{
    //properties of this IPart implementation
}
```

This classes is entities. Your data service must implement logic for saving and cascade operations.
Sample wcf service(from my project):

```
[EnableClientAccess]
public class ModelService : LinqToEntitiesDomainService<dpirtEntities>
{
    public void InsertZone(Zone zone)
        {
            if ((zone.EntityState != EntityState.Detached))
            {
                this.ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(zone, EntityState.Added);
            }
            else
            {
                this.ObjectContext.Zones.AddObject(zone);
            }
        }

        public void UpdateZone(Zone currentZone)
        {
            Zone originalZone = this.ChangeSet.GetOriginal(currentZone);
            if ((currentZone.EntityState == EntityState.Detached))
            {
                if (originalZone != null)
                {
                    this.ObjectContext.Zones.AttachAsModified(currentZone, originalZone);
                }
                else
                {
                    this.ObjectContext.Zones.Attach(currentZone);
                }
            }

            foreach (Document doc in this.ChangeSet.GetAssociatedChanges(currentZone, o => o.Documents))
            {
                ChangeOperation op = this.ChangeSet.GetChangeOperation(doc);
                switch (op)
                {
                    case ChangeOperation.Insert:
                        if ((doc.EntityState != EntityState.Added))
                        {
                            if ((doc.EntityState != EntityState.Detached))
                            {
                                this.ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(doc, EntityState.Added);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                this.ObjectContext.AddToDocuments(doc);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case ChangeOperation.Update:
                        this.ObjectContext.Documents.AttachAsModified(doc, this.ChangeSet.GetOriginal(doc));
                        break;
                    case ChangeOperation.Delete:
                        if (doc.EntityState == EntityState.Detached)
                        {
                            this.ObjectContext.Attach(doc);
                        }
                        this.ObjectContext.DeleteObject(doc);
                        break;
                    case ChangeOperation.None:
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        public void DeleteZone(Zone zone)
        {
            if ((zone.EntityState == EntityState.Detached))
            {
                this.ObjectContext.Zones.Attach(zone);
            }
            this.ObjectContext.Zones.DeleteObject(zone);
        }
}
```

Comment: Okay. But when I am loading the main object. How does the main object know about it parts?

Comment: For example create factory of parts - PartsFactory. And in main object constructor get parts from factory

Comment: So in the PartsFactory, I define which parts I have? And how do I save a part using a service? In my case, the service contains methods like Save, Update, Delete, GetPartById, etc.

Comment: In parts factory you define logic for obtaining part by some criteria like main object characteristics.

Comment: For save/update/delete/etc you may create some "parts holder", that can do this operations. And parts factory must solve which part needed when main objects requests their parts

Comment: Parts configuration for main object may be readed by factory. Main object not required to know about parts.

Comment: Thnx. How does such a parts holder look like? Where do I have to think about?

Comment: I don't get it. If I save the main object, the related parts must also be saved (same for update and delete). I mean, every part has it's own service. How should I do this? Maybe you can provide some code?

Answer (score 0):

Have a `List` or `Dictionary` in your `Main` class and store the references to the different objects.

**For example:**

All the tabs implement an interface called `IScreenTab`.

```
class MainTab : IScreenTab
{

    // Store a map of scree name to screen object
    // You can also just use a List<IScreenTab> 
    private Dictionary<string, IScreenTab> m_OtherScreens;

    // Your implementation goes here
    public MainTab(){ }
    public MainTab(List<IScreenTab> screenTabList){ }
    public AddTab(string screenName, IScreenTab screenTabObj){ }

}
```

Comment: Okay. But when I am loading the main object. How does the main object know about it parts?

Comment: Check my edit, you need to either pass it in the constructor or explictly add them later.

Comment: Why does MainTab inherits from IScreenTab? What is in IScreenTab? (ps: I've edited my startpost)

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar in the past, and I decoupled my GUI from my domain design by using an IoC container.  In my code I used StructureMap, which was very easy to adopt.

I had exactly the same setup in which there was an 'editor' which contained a number of 'tabs'.  Each tab could either contain some different view of my 'object' or it could show an item from collections stored within the 'object'.  So there were a number of *static* and *variable* tabs.

So, I needed two things.
1. A way to create an editor, with the correct number of tabs.
2. A way to create the tab, plus all it's controls.

So, I created an interface for each, which looked loosely like this.

```
public interface IEditorFactory<TObject>
{
    Editor CreateEditor(TObject instance);
}

public interface ITabEditorFactory<TObject>
{
    void CreateTab(TObject instance, Editor parent);
}
```

I'll leave Editor up to your imagination.  By in my app it was a custom UserControl, with various features and behaviour.

Next, imagine we had a Person, who had personal info, an Address an multiple contracts.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
    public string NationalInsuranceNumber { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Contract> Contracts { get; }
}
```

My app wanted to display one 'Personal Details' tab, one 'Employment' tab, one 'Address' tab and multiple 'Contract' tabs.

I implemented the following.
    public class PersonalTab : ITabEditorFactory { ... }
    public class EmployeeTab : ITabEditorFactory { ... }
    public class AddressTab : ITabEditorFactory { ... }
    public class ContractTab : ITabEditorFactory { ... }

Notice how #1 and #2 implement the same ITabEditorFactory.  That's because they both display different aspects of the Person.

But before I had implemented those I implemented the PersonEditor
    public class PersonEditor : IEditorFactory { ... }
It was good that I implemented this first, as it forced de-coupling my editor factory from all the tab factories.  I wouldn't accidentally slip in any references to concrete classes.  My editor factory just knew how to ask for a ITabEditorFactory<> for the Person, Address and Contract classes.

My final solution was a little more complicated than I outlined above, as it also covered Editor re-use for different instances, how to handle multiple (or no) tab editors for any a single class, and being able to define security on a tab-by-tab basis.

The end result was that I had a GUI model that was decoupled from my domain, and was extensible without requiring me to change a single line of existing code.

Lovely jubbly.